# Screen: can I execute commands and split the window when starting screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I use the `screen` command on several servers, where I monitor several log files. I arrange the log files to my preferences with several splits and by naming the regions. Sometimes the server gets rebooted or I have to log out from the screen session for various reasons, and it is tedious to set the this up manually every time. Is there a way to script this somehow, so that screen opens up with e.g. three split regions initially with specific names and executes a command in each region?

Comment: There was a similar question on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/687348/how-to-persist-gnu-screen-layout-after-restart You may wish to check out `terminator` that I mention in my answer there. Not exactly what you're asking since it's not `screen`-based but should be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the answer. Terminator sounds interesting, I was not aware of that. Unfortunately, I'm using SuSE Linux 11 and am not allowed to install additional binaries.

Comment: @simon you can use a standalone version of terminator by downloading a [pre-compiled latest version](https://launchpad.net/terminator/trunk/0.97/+download/terminator-0.97.tar.gz) it from its [project page](https://launchpad.net/terminator), extracting it and running the `terminator` executable. Did saving the `screen` layout work for u?

Comment: @wilf, thanks for the suggestions. Saving the screen layout did not work - I assume that the screen version installed is too old: "4.00.02 (FAU) 5-Dec-03" Using the pre-compiled executable is unfortunately also out of the question, because of security reasons - I can only run programs from the official distribution or pre-approved in my organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `~/.screenrc` on the server.

example:

```
split
screen -t top top
focus
screen -t shell
```

where:

`split` — splits current window/region horizontally

`focus` — switch to next region

`screen -t name [command]` — set name for current window/region and run `command`

Comment: Thanks, this works. In my case I don't have an own user account, but I created a separate configuration file and start screen with the -c option to specify the configuration file.